# use maven3 in IPV4 network but throws a IPV6 throws A IPV6 exception

Tags: java, maven, network-protocols

I am run a maven command "mvn -e install" in my computer ,my network is IP4V but it throw IPV6 exception,How do  I use JAVA or maven OPTIONS to switch to IPV4 network.

```
。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。。
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: 10.10.19.4:18081/nexu
s
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInput
Data(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:799)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:11
6)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.
run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 10.10.19.4:18081/nexus
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1201)

        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultCli
entConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultCli
entConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:130)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPo
olEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPo
。。。。。。。。。。。
```

Comment: it looks that your dns seemed to be not working correctly. Or the server where you run nexus does not accept IP4 connection. That's more a network problem.

Comment: You have more than a hostname in the UnknownHostException message. That's suspicious. How does it appear in your pom?

Answer (score 8):

How about passing `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` when executing Maven since it is a Java program. For example:

`mvn -e install -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`